# Как получить максимальное значение id?

Tags: php, wordpress, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

В базе данных  wordpress есть таблица, по умолчанию называемая wp-post. Её значение я выбрал 
примерно так:

```
$sql="SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM wp_posts ";
```

Это функция, и не вся её часть, но главное, код вар-дампом вывел значение, получил следующее:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["MAX(`id`)"]=> string(5) "11373" } }
```

Вот теперь вопрос: как мне получить значение ключа `"MAX(`id`)"`, учитывая, что он хранится в массиве второго уровня?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$id = 0;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `max` FROM `wp_posts`");

if($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data = reset($data);
    $id = $data['max'];
}
```

Типа того..